# Kendo UI Grid: entering invalid date in date filter. No warning to the user

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Entering an invalid date in a Kendo UI Grid filter. The filter is not applied and the user doesn't get any warning. 
Is there a way to add a validation to the input of a date filter?
Or to force the user to use the date picker?

[image: Invalid date in Kendo UI Grid Filter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include a validator for the input element. I found an example online which you might find [helpful](http://dojo.telerik.com/@rusev/uMEJ)